# How to get the data from OR condition in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have three parameters.Fromdate,todate,and policy number. Among these three parameters fromdate and todate are mandatory and policy number is optional parameter.

1. If  I select only from date and to date(without selecting policy number) I'm getting expected all policy number details within daterange.
   2.If I select from date ,to date and policy number also. I should get only that particular policy number details within daterange. But getting all the policy number details within daterange

I'm getting all the policy number details. But I expecting particular policy number details[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvwRm.png)

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text, not as an image. If you need both conditions to be true, why are you using `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have an `OR` which means either the date range or the policy number can match (but also see [the precedence rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80__BABBCFGD).)

With your fixed values you would need:

```
WHERE CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE >= DATE '2021-10-01'
AND CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE < DATE '2023-11-14'
AND pm.policy_number='605000057'
```

I've changed your string values like `'01-10-2023'` to actual dates so you aren't relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings; and changed the end of the range to the following day - which means you don't need to `TRUNC()` the column value. You didn't need to for the 'from' date anyway; but doing it for either means it can't use a normal index on that column because of the function being applied.

More generally, if you are passing in the values as parameters you could do:

```
WHERE CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE >= P_FROM_DATE
AND CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE < P_TO_DATE
AND (P_POLICY_NUMBER IS NULL OR pm.policy_number = P_POLICY_NUMBER)
```

supplying the `P_FROM_DATE` parameter value as the equivalent of `DATE '2023-10-01'`, `P_DATE_TO` as `DATE '2023-11-14'`, and `P_POLICY_NUMBER` as *either* null *or* the specific policy you want. If it is null then the first part of the `OR` condition is always matched and you'll see data for any policy (subject to the date range, of course); if it is not null then the second part of the `OR` will only match the specific policy you supply, so you will only see data for that one.

If you still want to pass the end-date as `DATE '2023-11-13'` as in your original query then you can add one to it:

```
WHERE CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE >= P_FROM_DATE
AND CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE < P_TO_DATE + 1
AND (P_POLICY_NUMBER IS NULL OR pm.policy_number = P_POLICY_NUMBER)
```

which would still give you all details for any time on the 13th.

`CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE < P_TO_DATE + 1` is equivalent to `TRUNC(CP.PAYMENT_REF_DATE) <= P_TO_DATE` but doesn't require the function to be applied to every date value in that column to find matching rows.